# Can't refer to another schema when using mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two Schema which i named User and Teacher. I want the teacher_id in Teacher schema to be refer to ObjectID in User Schema. I'm using mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId for the references. Problem is when i'm inserting data to Teacher collection, there is no teacher_id. Seems like there is no objectID was referred to. Here is my code

**Teacher**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var TeacherSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({

    subject: {
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },

    level: {
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },


    second_subject: {
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },

    teacher_id: [{

        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'User'




    }]

});

var Teacher = mongoose.model('Teacher', TeacherSchema);
module.exports = Teacher;
```

**User**

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  username: { 
    type: String, 
    unique: true, 
    required: true, 
    trim: true
  },

  password: {
    type: String, 
    required: true,
  },

  roles: {
    type:String,
    required:true,
  },

  name: {
    type:String,
    required:true,
  },

  flag:{
    type:Number,
  },
});
```

**Server Side**

```
router.post('/register', function (req, res, next) {
    if (
      req.body.username &&
      req.body.password,
      req.body.name,
      req.body.roles ) {

      var userData = {
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password,
        name: req.body.name,
        roles: req.body.roles
      }

      //use schema.create to insert data into the db
      User.create(userData, function (err, user) {
        if (err)
        {
          return next(err)
        } else 
        {
          if(user.roles=='Admin')
          {
            console.log('Admin Registered');
            return res.redirect('/admin_user');
          }
          if(req.body.subject && req.body.secondary_subject,req.body.level)
          {
                var teacherData = {
                  subject: req.body.subject,
                  second_subject: req.body.secondary_subject,
                  level: req.body.level,
                  teacher_id: req.body._id,

              }
              console.log(req.body);
              Teacher.create(teacherData, function (err, teacher){
                if(err){
                    return next(err)
                }else
                {
                    console.log('Teacher details added'+teacher)
                    return res.redirect('/admin_user');
                }
            });
          }else
          {
            var err = new Error('All fields have to be filled out');
            err.status = 400;
            return next(err);
          }

        }
      });

    } 
    else
    {
      var err = new Error('All fields have to be filled out');
      err.status = 400;
      return next(err);
    }

  });
```

Comment: Looks like you are not passing `teacher_id` field when creating `Teacher` document

Comment: How to do that? @Vishnu

Comment: Assuming you already have the `User` document  `_id` field in a variable `userId`. You should `teacher_id: [userId]` also to `teacherData` and then save

Comment: how to assign `_id` filed to variable `userId?` i'm using mongoDB default for ObjectID @Vishnu

Comment: Can you please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77540162/unable-to-fetch-a-field-from-a-table-in-react/77540481?noredirect=1#comment136699940_77540481