# can't ref the other mongoose Schema when using ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i recently encountered a problem, when i set up a mongoose schema, i have two schemas.One is userSchema and the other one is courseSchema.i tried to set the objectid and ref to the userSchema.Things happened.as you guys can see, i just can't set the instructor type to mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,it never show in my mongoose database. I want to know where i do wrong.[image: courseSchema][image: userSchema]

Comment: Please do not post images of your code, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3761628

Comment: could you try once with ref:"Users" // notice the plural

Comment: if it does not work, please post the code where you are trying to add a new document in the course collection, also make sure you have some document in Users collection

Comment: i changed it to Users, it still not worked. i think a year ago, someone also asked this question,but it has no correct answer.This really bothered me for so long

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62355996/cant-refer-to-another-schema-when-using-mongoose-schema-types-objectid this article the same question as me